# Insert character before and after of character but ignore space between two characters

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

How can I insert the character before and after in a character but ignore whitespace between two character or more.

I try this regex but it's return incorrectly

```php
$str = "        echo '<pre>';";
$replaces = preg_replace('/(\S{3,})/', '[:$1:]',$str);
var_dump($replaces);
```

But it's return this following

```php
        [:echo:] [:'<pre>';:]
```

What  I want is this

```php
        [:echo '<pre>';:]
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: `preg_replace('~\S{3,}(?:\s\S{3,})*~', '[:$0:]', $str)`?

Comment: thanks it's working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either of

```php
preg_replace('~\S{3,}(?:\s\S{3,})*~', '[:$0:]', $str)?
preg_replace('~\S+(?:\s\S+)*~', '[:$0:]', $str)?
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tLyaoV/1). The `\S{3,}` matches three or more consecutive non-whitespace chars while `\S+` matches one or more of these chars.

Note you do not need to enclose the whole match with a capturing group, you may use `$0` in the replacement pattern to refer to the whole match.